# Neo4J Movie-Graph - actors with same age

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to analyze in Neo4J with the movie data set provided (: play movie-graph) those actors who were born in the same year, and then perform a query that allows me to obtain which actors of the same age have worked together. To do this, I have tried to create a relationship type "HAS_SAME_AGE" in the database between actors who were born in the same year, but it gave me an error and I don't know how to continue.

This is what I have written:

`MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person) WHERE a.born=b.born WITH a AS PersonA, b AS PersonB MERGE (PersonA)- [:HAS_SAME_AGE]-(PersonB)`

Can someone help me fill in the correct code? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is bad practice to add redundant data (eg, relationships that duplicate information you can already get from the DB in other ways) unless there is a really good reason for it (eg, you cannot meet a strict performance requirement otherwise).

   It is easy to get all actors born in the same year without a relationship. For example:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person)
   RETURN p.born AS year, COLLECT(p) AS actors
   ```

   So, unless you have a critical need to get the same information a little faster, you should just use the above kind of query instead of storing redundant relationships.
2. However, if you *really* do need to add the relationships, you can do something like this:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person)
   WITH p.born AS year, COLLECT(p) AS ps
   UNWIND apoc.coll.combinations(ps, 2) AS pair
   WITH pair[0] AS p1, pair[1] AS p2
   MERGE (p1)-[:HAS_SAME_AGE]-(p2)
   ```

   The APOC function [apoc.coll.combinations](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.combinations/) is used to generate distinct pairs of actors born in the same year.